# Custom display based on Woocommerce product variations stock data checkbox option

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I am trying to add a custom message to variation products, based on their stock quantity and stock status.

So far I got this:

```
function load_variation_settings_fields( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {

    // Display shipping delay text when stock quantity exist
    if( $variation->get_stock_quantity() > 0 )
        $variation_data['text_field'] = __('<p class="stock in-stock">Stock: <span>På lager</span><br>Delivery: <span>2-12 hverdage</span></p>'); 
    else $variation_data['text_field'] = __('<p class="stock in-stock">Stock: <span>Out of stock</span><br>Delivery: <span>4-6 weeks</span></p>');

    return $variation_data;
}
```

It works, and displays the message based on the quantity of each variation, but I need this to only work for one type of stock status (a custom one).
I would need to display a different message for a different variation stock status.
This is what I have tried:

```
function load_variation_settings_fields( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {

    // Display shipping delay text when stock quantity exist
    if( $variation->get_stock_quantity() > 0 && ($stockstatus == 'customstatus'))
        $variation_data['text_field'] = __('<p class="stock in-stock">Stock: <span>In stock</span><br>Delivery: <span>2-12 days</span></p>'); 
    elseif ( ($stockstatus == 'customstatus') )
    $variation_data['text_field'] = __('<p class="stock in-stock">Stock: <span>Out of stock</span><br>Delivery: <span>4-6 weeks</span></p>');

    return $variation_data;
}
```

It is displayed with this, in the variation.php file:

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation-custom-text-field">{{{ data.variation.text_field }}}</div>
```

**EDIT:**
This is my latest attempt, as my custom stock status is stored in the '_stock_status' meta value. Still doesn't work though.

```
    function load_variation_settings_fields( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    $stockstatus = $product->get_attribute( '_stock_status' );
if( ($stockstatus == 'bestillingsvare') ) {
        // Display shipping delay text when stock quantity exist
        if( $variation->get_stock_quantity() > 0 )
            $variation_data['text_field'] = __('<p class="stock in-stock">Stock: <span>På lager</span><br>Delivery: <span>2-12 hverdage</span></p>'); 
        else $variation_data['text_field'] = __('<p class="stock in-stock">Stock: <span>Out of stock</span><br>Delivery: <span>4-6 weeks</span></p>');
  }
        return $variation_data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we don't know really how you set your custom status 'bestillingsvare', it's not possible to reproduce the problem. Next time, it should be `necessary` to add all related code in your question.

So here is a similar working solution, with an additional custom setting in your product variations **that works for real**.

First, you need to add the following line in `/single-product/add-to-cart/variation.php` template file:

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation-delivery">{{{ data.variation.delivery_html }}}</div>
```

Then the revisited complete code:

```
// Add variation custom checkbox setting option field
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options', 'add_variation_delivery_status_option', 20, 3 );
function add_variation_delivery_status_option ( $loop, $variation_data, $post_object ) {
    $checked = get_post_meta( $post_object->ID, '_delivery_option', true ) ? true : false;
    ?>
    <label class="tips" data-tip="<?php _e( 'Enable', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
    <?php _e( 'Delivery?', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox variation_delivery_option" name="delivery_option_<?php
        echo $loop; ?>" <?php checked( $checked, true ); ?> />
    </label>
    <?php
}

// Save variation custom checkbox setting option field value
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_delivery_status_option', 20, 2 );
function save_variation_delivery_status_option( $variation_id, $i ) {
    $value = isset( $_POST['delivery_option_'.$i] ) ? true : false;
    update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_delivery_option', $value );
}

// Display in front end the delivery info
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'display_variation_delivery_status_option', 20, 3 );
function display_variation_delivery_status_option( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    if( get_post_meta( $variation->get_id(), '_delivery_option', true ) ) {
        $stock_qty      = $variation->get_stock_quantity();

        $stock_class    = $stock_qty > 0 ? 'stock in-stock' : 'stock out-of-stock';
        $stock_label    = $stock_qty > 0 ? __('På lager') : __('Out of stock');
        $delivery_delay = $stock_qty > 0 ? __('2-12 hverdage') : __('4-6 weeks');

        // Display a shipping delay text when stock quantity exist
        $variation_data['delivery_html'] = sprintf(
            '<p class="%s">' . __('Stock') . ': <span>%s</span><br>
            ' . __('Delivery') . ': <span>%s</span></p>',
            $stock_class, $stock_label, $delivery_delay
        );
    }
    return $variation_data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

In backend variation settings (enabling the delivery option):

[image]

In Front-end option activated when "In stock":

[image]

In Front-end option activated when "Out of stock":

[image]

> But as you see **to avoid duplicated information**, you could use existing `availability_html` to change the displayed data adding your delivery information to it instead.

In this case you will not override /single-product/add-to-cart/variation.php template  as it is not needed any more, and you will replace in the last function

```
$variation_data['delivery_html']
```

by

```
$variation_data['availability_html']
```

Making the necessary other changes to the code, to get the desired display.

Comment: Thank you so much. With your code, I managed to get it working with my own custom meta.

Answer (score 0):

You can get code status lie:

```
// Compatibility for WC versions from 2.5.x to 3.0+
if ( method_exists( $product, 'get_stock_status' ) ) {
     $stockstatus = $product->get_stock_status(); // For version 3.0+
} else {
     $stockstatus = $product->stock_status; // Older than version 3.0
}
```

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain a bit more? I can see how to get my custom status in this (which has post meta value '_stock_status')